# EhCache - Manual Replication not working

Tags: replication, rmi, ehcache

I am trying to set up Manual Replication for Ehcache for to two different servers. Below is my  configuraion:

```
<cache name="codeTaskCache" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false"
 timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0" overflowToDisk="false" />


 <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class=
                      "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
                      properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
                      rmiUrls=//server1:40001/codeTaskCache |     //server2:40001/codeTaskCache"
                      propertySeparator="," />`
```

The same configuration is present on both tomcat server which are running on two different unix boxes.

Replication works fine from server1 -> server2 but NOT from server2 -> server1 which is pretty strange.

In document they have a statement 'The rmiUrls is a list of the cache peers of the server being configured. Do not include the server being configured in the list.'

But if it works one way then why not the other way? Could someone please throw some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just been bothered with quite the similar problem, maybe my post can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314121/ehcache-not-replicating-solution/

Comment: Thanks Oddbeck, but I am not using the cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory .

Comment: But surely you must let the server know what port it's supposed to listen to locally for incoming connections from the other server - how do you resolve this at the moment?

Comment: I did not! But the cache was getting updated from Server1 -> Server2 with just the configuration that I have mentioned in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

The RMI urls should not point to itself, just the other ehcache instances - at least that's what worked for me.

Also make sure the hostnames are resolvable from both servers, and in the last desperate attempt you can even try to have "hostname=name_of_server_dot_domain_dot_com" in the listening statement of the listener part XML.